# How to give href links in custom modules for multilingual site?

Tags: 7, navigation, i18n-l10n

I've created a custom module,having a href links like follows.

Let's say the following link appears on `example.com/somepage/another-page/nid`

```
t('<p><a class="stn" href="/my-page">Back to My Page</a></p>');
```

The above links works by default but it won't work if user is in Spanish version (`example.com/es/somepage/another-page/nid`).

If user click on the link it redirects to default lang version (`example.com/my-page`)

I tried `$GLOBALS['base_url']` but it doesn't work in this case.

So my question is how can I give href link for multilingual? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using http://example.com instead of commercial website in your content, please.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for the suggestion I've changed it. Infact mydomain.com is not ours.I didn't know that domain exists :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your code.

Wrong:

```
t('<p><a class="stn" href="/my-page">Back to My Page</a></p>');
```

Correctly

```
'<p>' . l(t('Back to My Page'), 'my-page', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('stn')))) . '</p>';
```

For more information see function [l();](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

Comment: I see we both used the same code snippet from the same api docs page :D

Comment: Yes, thanks for that but that didn't resolve my problem. If user is in Spanish version that redirects to example.com/my-page instead of example.com/es/my-page

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`l`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
l(t('Back to My Page'), 'my-page', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('whatever-class-you-need-if-any))));
```

It is there to take care about all that irritating details for you.

Comment: Molot are you sure that it works on Spanish version too? Am I missing something?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan it should preserve your language, and allow Drupal configuration to happen - if you configured Drupal to direct users to content in their current language, then it will (or, at least, should).